# access a class instance/variable from one running python file in another?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, data-analysis

I have a problem that involves collecting data continuously from multiple sources.

My setup as it is currently, writes each data entry from each source to a MySQL db, and then, with another python program, does Select's that bring all the data together. I need to make INSERT's at roughly 1000/second and as it is my SELECT's can take 15-20 seconds each.

The whole process takes so long the data is obsolete before I get to do anything useful with it.

I have created a toy example to try and demonstrate what I am looking for.

program 1 'generateClasses':

```
import time
import random
from datetime import datetime

class Race:

    def __init__(self,name):

        hist        = {}
        now         = datetime.now()
        self.name   = name
        self.now    = now
        hist[now]   = 0
        self.v      = 0
        self.hist   = hist    # example variable's.


    def update(self,name,v):

        now         = datetime.now()
        hist        = self.hist
        hist[now]   =  v
        self.v      = v
        self.now    - now
        self.hist   = hist


class Looper:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.a      = Race(name)

    def loop(self,name):

        #  simulating the streaming API
        while True:
            v = self.a.v
            v += 1
            self.a.update(name,v)
            print(a,datetime.now(),v)   # can i access this stream using the location displayed with the print(a)?
            time.sleep(0.1)  # this should be more like time.sleep(0.001)

    def pickData(self,name):
        v = self.v
        self.loop(name)
        print('The state at {} {} = '.format(self.now,self.v))
        return self.hist


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = 'Some_ID'
    a = Looper(x)
    a.loop(x)
```

program 2:

```
from  generateClasses import Looper
from datetime import datetime
import time

start_time  = int((datetime.now() - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds())
print(start_time)

x = 'Some_orher_ID'
a = Looper(x)
print('this will print')
a.loop(x)
print('this wont ever print')
a.pickdata(x)


# this last section is the functionality i am looking for in this program, but, as it is, it will never run.

x = ‘Some_ID’

while True:
    now_time  = int((datetime.now() - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds())
    print(start_time)
    if int(now_time-start_time) == 10:
        a.pickData(x)
        # b.pickData(x)  
        # c.pickData(x)  
        # d.pickData(x)
        # make further actions.....
```

What happens currently in my examples is that it creates its own loop using the class structure from the first program. 
What I want it to do is call the the pickData() method from program 2 at timely intervals of my choosing on a loop running in another program.

Is my best option picking a db located in memory and getting a faster computer?

Maybe something can be done with the object location shown when you print the instance name?

[I have uploaded to github if anybody fancies it..](https://github.com/ashreid23/variable_sharing)

I would be grateful of any suggestions.
also, recommendations for further reading would be appreciated also.

Comment: I'm unclear on how the example demonstrates the question. You ultimately want to have a process that is writing data to an mysql database, while another process quickly queries from it, but your SELECT statements are too slow. Is that correct? In that case I would suggest using table indexes or other tricks to make selects faster. I don't see how your MWE relates to the question though

Comment: My example is a simplified version of my issue, I have one program that collates data and adds it to a class Race. In my example the while loop contains a counter. In the real problem is a streaming API, the functionality, for explanatory purposes, is the same. In the other program I have a while loop generating time-series data from a number of sources, the steaming API being one of them.     MySQL is one solution I have yet to make work for me (that doesn’t rule out a possibility that it can work) I am just wondering if there is a different/better way to look at it.

Comment: I am confused because you are mentioning multiple programs, but here you have a single program, as far as I can tell. Or are you running *both* of these source files as scripts? Anyway, for speed, you might consider an in-memory solution, perhaps redis

Comment: both files as scripts..  redis, will look into that now thanks